# Write author instead of dash in references with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I use

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid, maxnames=1, maxbibnames=6, minbibnames=6, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

to format my references. This will display it as follows: 
[image: printed references in document]

Now I would like the last reference (TRCRC (2015b)) to be displayed as such and not just a dash -- (2015b). I found similar questions but many people ask how to write a dash instead of the author, I would like to do the opposite.

Comment: Does  the option `dashed=false` help ?`

Comment: Perfect, yes that's it :-)

Comment: @Guido Sounds like an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's

```
dashed=false
```

Thanks to [Guido](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16895/guido)

Comment: I'd give time for Guido to post the answer himself. that way, he can receive some persistent credit for his knowledge :)